# Dump large data to csv file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

Using JavaScript, i need to put the data in a csv file.

My code:

```
var csv = Papa.unparse(this.data,{
                            quotes: false,
                            delimiter: ",",
                            newline: "\r\n"
                    });              
var a         = document.createElement('a');
a.href        = 'data:attachment/csv,' + escape(csv);
a.download    = 'download.csv';
a.click();
```

Var csv contains the entire data. The issue is that browser crashes whenever there is large data in the variable. Browser crashes at last step i.e. `a.click();`

How can i fix this? Can i stream the data to a file from JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Using WebWorkers might be a solution.
WebWorkers can process large amounts of data in the background process, while keeping application UI responsive:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp